# Intersection of two spans paradox

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, determinant

How would I find the intersection of two spans?

Consider the vectors contained in the span "S"

$$U_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$U_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 & 4 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$U_{3} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$U_{4} = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 & 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

In REF, A basis of these vectors are:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & -2 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 & 6 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

This basis spans $R^3$

Another basis called T consists of

$$V_{1} = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 3 & 4 & -5 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$V_{2} = \begin{bmatrix} 7 & 7 & 14 & 11 \end{bmatrix}$$

These are LI and form a plane $R^2$

The question is what is the span of the intersection of the two spans?

$$S = \lambda_{1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 4  \end{bmatrix}+  \lambda_{3} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$T = \lambda_{4} \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{5} \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 7 \\ 14 \\ 11  \end{bmatrix}$$

Setting them equal

$$\lambda_{1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 4  \end{bmatrix}+  \lambda_{3} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda_{4} \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{5} \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 7 \\ 14 \\ 11  \end{bmatrix}$$

Notice $v_{2}$ is in the span of s, therefore can be expressed as a linear combination of $u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}$ so dissappears from our equation encapsulated in a new coefficient of lambda

Rearranging our equation and Turing it into a single matrix yields:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&2 \\ -1&3&0&-3 \\ -2&6&0&-4 \\ 0&4&1&5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{1} \\ \lambda_{2}\\\lambda_{3}  \\ \lambda_{4} \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

This represents the intersection, when solving , I get the all lambda equal 0 and hence the intersection is of dimension 0 at a single point.

However when using the dimension formula

Dim(s) + dim(t) - dim(t+s) = dim(intersection), I get that the dimension is 1, and is a straight line. Which is also what my marks scheme says.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: $v_2$ is in $S,$ not $v_1$

Comment: Thanks fixed the typo

Comment: When you said $v_2$ is in the span of $S$ then that means that that vector is in the intersection of the two spaces.  While it is okay to set it aside, you can't just throw it out.  When after setting it aside, you see that what is left is a non-singular matrix,  then $v_2$ is exactly the intersection of the two spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $v_2$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $u_1,$ $u_2$ and $u_3$ does not mean that it should be removed from the equation. Keep the fifth column and the $\lambda_5.$ The solution of the resulting system of equations will be a one-dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{R}^5,$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \\ \lambda_3 \\
\lambda_4 \\ \lambda_5 \end{bmatrix}
= \mu \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\
a_4 \\ a_5 \end{bmatrix}\;\;,\;\;\mu\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
You can now use one of the sides of
$$\lambda_{1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ -2 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{2} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 3 \\ 6 \\ 4  \end{bmatrix}+  \lambda_{3} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 
0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda_{4} \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{5} \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 7 \\ 14 \\ 11  \end{bmatrix}$$
to get the points of the line that forms the intersection. If we take the right side:
$$
x = \lambda_{4} \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5  \end{bmatrix}+ \lambda_{5} \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 7 \\ 14 \\ 11  \end{bmatrix}
= \mu \left( a_{4} \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ -5  \end{bmatrix}+ a_{5} \begin{bmatrix} 7 \\ 7 \\ 14 \\ 11  \end{bmatrix}\right) 
\;\;,\;\;\mu\in\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: Why can't we remove the fifth vector? Writing it as a linear combination of the first three we can write it  as $$\lambda_{5} \vec{v_{2}} = \lambda_{5} (a\vec{u_{1}}+b\vec{u_{2}} + c \vec{u_{3}})$$ each component has e.g $(\lambda a) \vec{u_{1}}$ which minus from the others side of the equation gets us that the new coefficient of e.g $\vec{u}_{1}$ is $(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{5} a )\vec{u_{1}}$ which is just some new coefficient $\lambda_{1}' $ doing the same for the others yields the same result , which is just  the same span, s

Comment: Absolutely correct. And in this case, you get $\lambda_1'=\lambda_2'=\lambda_3'=\lambda_4=0.$ But the system $\lambda_1-\lambda_5a=\lambda_1'=0,$ $\lambda_2-\lambda_5b=\lambda_2'=0,$ $\lambda_3-\lambda_5c=\lambda_3'=0,$ has three equations and four unknowns ($\lambda_1,$ $\lambda_2,$ $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_5$) so you have still one degree of freedom, which will result in the line in question.

Comment: @jensenpaull consider what it means to eliminate $\lambda_5$ in terms of the spans. Can you see how that implies there is a non-trivial intersection?

Comment: How did you get a line in $R^{5}$, I get a different answer, the line spanned by $V_{2}$

Comment: @jensenpaull The valid lambdas form a line in $\mathbb{R}^5.$ The line you are looking for is then obtained by either using $\lambda_1,$ $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$ and put it into the left side of your equation OR using $\lambda_4$ (which must be $0$) and $\lambda_5$ and put it into the right side of the equation. Be careful not to mix the space in which the lambdas "live" with the space in which your planes, hyperplanes and lines live.